# Python string formatting with "write"

Tags: python

I have some code like this:

```
#w = open("blabla.py", "w") is already called
w.write("Button(root, text = %s,command=%s).grid(row=%s,column=%s)\n" % textvalue,buttoncommand,str(rowvalue),str(columnvalue))
```

However, if I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

What is wrong?

Comment: yes. They all are assigned to values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose vars into a tuple:

```
w.write("Button(root, text = %s,command=%s).grid(row=%s,column=%s)\n" % (textvalue,buttoncommand,str(rowvalue),str(columnvalue)))
```

Or use a better format version:

```
w.write("Button(root, text = {0},"
      "command={1}).grid(row={2},"
      "column={3})\n".format(textvalue,
                             buttoncommand,
                             str(rowvalue),
                             str(columnvalue)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I will also try the .format() version also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the format arguments into a tuple (add parentheses):

`... % (textvalue,buttoncommand,str(rowvalue),str(columnvalue))`

but the `%` syntax for formatting strings is becoming outdated. Try this:

`"'{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}'".format(textvalue,buttoncommand,str(rowvalue),str(columnvalue))`

Answer (score 0):

If you pass multiple arguments to a format string you need to put them in brackets:

```
w.write("Button(root, text = %s,command=%s).grid(row=%s,column=%s)\n" % (textvalue,buttoncommand,str(rowvalue),str(columnvalue)))
                                                                        ^                                                      ^
```

You also might want to take a look at the new format syntax: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples